# Where can I edit the shortcuts in the firefox source code

Tags: firefox

(I'm on macos btw)

I would like to edit the shortcut for opening a new private window in firefox. It's currently set to `Cmd` + `Shift` + `p`, but I'd like to set it to `Cmd` + `Shift` + `n` since I'm switching from chrome and I'd like to preserve shortcuts across both browsers. I already tried editing the shortcuts from system preference, but it didn't work, and according to this [superuser answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342978/why-shift-cmd-n-fails-as-a-custom-shortcut-for-firefox-new-private-window), this has been a known issue. Now this superuser answer mentions that he compiled firefox from source to work around those keyboard shortcuts issues. I'd like to do the same, but it's my first time looking at the firefox source code and I don't know were to look at. So if there's anyone that knows which file(s) I should edit to change this specific shortcut, it'd be greatly appreciated. I'm guessing it should be somewhere in the `devtools` folder.

Thanks.